# UIImage array to PDF Converting Memory Leak

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, memory, memory-leaks

I want to merge UIImage's on PDF Document, then It is sending to API as Data.

But in this method, there is a big memory leak! It is starting with 20 MB, then it is rising to 390 MB, finally memory is stabilizing on 300 MB.

What is wrong with this method?

```
fileprivate func mergeImages(_ images: Array<UIImage>)  {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).sync {
        let width: CGFloat = 768
        let height: CGFloat = 1024
        let pageSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height);
        let pageFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height);
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pageFrame, nil)
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        for i in 0 ..< images.count {
            autoreleasepool {
                let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(images[i].resize(toSize: pageSize)!, 0.8)
                let dp = CGDataProvider(data: jpegData! as CFData)
                let cgImage = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dp!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)

                UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
                ctx?.translateBy(x: 0, y: height)
                ctx?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
                ctx?.draw(cgImage!, in: pageFrame)
            }
            //image.drawInRect(pageFrame)
        }

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        let d = pdfData as Data
        self.completion?(d)
    }        
}
```

Comment: You should be looking at the "Debug Memory Graph" to verify if memory is being leaked. If so, it will give you some information to fix the issue.

Comment: @tersintersi why are you using CGImage object instead of direct drawing UIImage object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to Use **CGRelease** method for these objects

```
let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(images[i].resize(toSize: pageSize)!, 0.8)
let dp = CGDataProvider(data: jpegData! as CFData)
let cgImage = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dp!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
```

As I have doubt over autorelase pool to release those expensive objects later.

Comment: `let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(images[i].resize(toSize: pageSize)!, 0.8)` This nolonger works in Swift 4.2.

Comment: In Swift 4.2 it is now `images[i].resize(toSize: pageSize)!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)` as mentioned in the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624115-jpegdata

Comment: I did not find anything about CGRelease. Could you share an example about it @SachinVsSachin